# Call method using another applicationPool from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-8.5

I have website running on IIS 8.5 and I have few application pools sharing same application(under same physical path). Each application pool use different service account identity(due to security reasons i can't have one 'super account' with all permissions).

In my back end web api I have set of operations that has to be performed synchronously with different app pools. Let's say that I have method A that only AppPool1 has permission to run, and method B that takes data from A, and only AppPool2 has permission to run it. Is there any way to run method B from method A using different application pool?

I can pick which application pool i want to use on front end, but I don't want to send data from method A to front end and then pass it to method B due to security reasons.

Comment: Are you asking whether one website can make http requests against another website running on the same machine?

Comment: No, i have one website using few application pools. One application pool have access to database A, and other application pool have access to database B. I need to call database B using data from database A. So, from front end i call one method in controller using one app pool, and i need to call another method with different app pool. This second method is not in controller so i can't call it via http request(and i can't put it in controller for security reasons).

Comment: "I have few application pools sharing same application" how are you accomplishing this?

Comment: I'm sorry, i think this is missleading. Within IIS i have 4 applications and 4 application pools, one per application. But all those IIS applications point to the same physical path with real application.